# How can I obtain 2 new vectors from an existing vector in R?

Tags: r, math, data-manipulation

Given a vector of :

```
list <- c(x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y)
```

How can I obtain new vectors with only x and only y, so essentially  splitting the vector into odd and even indexes? The length of the list should not matter.

Comment: `split(list,seq_along(list)%%2)`.

Comment: `v1 <- list[c(TRUE, FALSE)]; v2 <- list[c(FALSE, TRUE)]`

Comment: ```lapply(c('x', 'y'), function(x){list[which(list == x)]})```